# dynamic form not submitting when display goes from none to block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have created a script that sends a form that sends a form, a form that is dynamic depending on users choices.

The form in the html side looks fine, the code in the jQuery side executes fine until the actual form submits, and nothing in the console log tells me there is anything wrong at all.

The only thing I can think of is that this form starts being a display:none; in the css and then becomes available ones the person clicks a button saying add new payments.

Here is the html side of things:

```
<div class="section-9">

  <form action="#" id="addform" method="post">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-12">

        <div class="table-responsive" id="addsection">

          <table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped">

            <thead>
              <th>Number</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th class="text-center">Installments</th>
              <th>Contact Name</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="addnumber" value="" placeholder="Enter CPO Number"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="addprice" value="" placeholder="Enter CPO Number"></td>
                <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger addi">Installments</a></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="addcontactname" value="" placeholder="Enter Contact Name"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>

          </table>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12" id="addformajax"></div>

      <div class="col-sm-12 margin-top-15">

        <p><button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="button">SUBMIT</button></p>

      </div>

    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

No need to show css as its only display none in the section-9 class.

```
$('#addnew').on('click', function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $('.section-9').show();

      //do the click button for cpo installments
      $('.addi').on('click', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var installmentAmount = '<p><select class="form-control" id="installment-ammount"><option value="0">Please Select How Many Installments Are Required</option>';

        for (var i = 1; i <= 60; i++) {

          if (i === 1) {
            installmentAmount += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + ' Month</option>';
          } else {
            installmentAmount += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + ' Months</option>';
          }

        }

        installmentAmount += '</select></p><div class="showinstallmentdates margin-top-20"></div>';

        $('#addformajax').html(installmentAmount);

        $('#installment-ammount').bind('input', function() {

          var buildDateForms = '<p class="red padding-top-20"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> <em>If all amounts are left empty the price will be distributed evenly across all dates</em></p>';
          var howManyInstallments = $(this).val();
          var addingIdNames = '';

          for (var hmi = 1; hmi <= howManyInstallments; hmi++) {

            buildDateForms += '<div class="form-group row"><div class="col-xs-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="adddate-' + hmi + '" placeholder="Enter Date To Be Paid" value=""></div><div class="col-xs-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="addprice-' + hmi + '" placeholder="Amount To Be Paid" value=""></div></div>';
            if (hmi == 1) {
              addingIdNames += '#adddate-' + hmi;
            } else {
              addingIdNames += ', #adddate-' + hmi;
            }

          }

          buildDateForms += '<input type="hidden" value="' + howManyInstallments + '" name="totalinstallments" id="totalinstallments">';
          buildDateForms += '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){ $("';
          buildDateForms += addingIdNames;
          buildDateForms += '").datepicker({});});<\/script>';

          if (howManyInstallments != 0) {
            $('.showinstallmentdates').html(buildDateForms);
          } else {
            $('.showinstallmentdates').html('');
          }

        });

      });

      $("#addform").on('submit', function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/Applications/Controllers/Quotes/ajax-add-sin.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: new FormData(this),
          contentType: false,
          cache: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function(sinData) {

            $('body').html(sinData);

          }
        });

      });

    });
```

Granted I am not amazing at jQuery as its not what I use a lot and I am sure a wiz would be able to chop this down to be more efficient and streamline but according to the console I have no issues, and the html looks good also when its all displayed so I can not see a reason why the form is not submitted.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add id to button

```
<button id="btn-add-form" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="button">SUBMIT</button>
```

Put script to document.ready function

Change ajax function to

```
$("#btn-add-form").on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Applications/Controllers/Quotes/ajax-add-sin.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (sinData) {
            $('body').html(sinData);
        }
    });
});
```

complete code:

```
  <html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <title>New Page 1</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#addnew').on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('.section-9').show();
                    //do the click button for cpo installments
                    $('.addi').on('click', function (event) {

                        event.preventDefault();
                        var installmentAmount = '<p><select class="form-control" id="installment-ammount"><option value="0">Please Select How Many Installments Are Required</option>';
                        for (var i = 1; i <= 60; i++) {

                            if (i === 1) {
                                installmentAmount += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + ' Month</option>';
                            } else {
                                installmentAmount += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + ' Months</option>';
                            }

                        }

                        installmentAmount += '</select></p><div class="showinstallmentdates margin-top-20"></div>';
                        $('#addformajax').html(installmentAmount);
                        $('#installment-ammount').bind('input', function () {

                            var buildDateForms = '<p class="red padding-top-20"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> <em>If all amounts are left empty the price will be distributed evenly across all dates</em></p>';
                            var howManyInstallments = $(this).val();
                            var addingIdNames = '';
                            for (var hmi = 1; hmi <= howManyInstallments; hmi++) {

                                buildDateForms += '<div class="form-group row"><div class="col-xs-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="adddate-' + hmi + '" placeholder="Enter Date To Be Paid" value=""></div><div class="col-xs-6"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="addprice-' + hmi + '" placeholder="Amount To Be Paid" value=""></div></div>';
                                if (hmi == 1) {
                                    addingIdNames += '#adddate-' + hmi;
                                } else {
                                    addingIdNames += ', #adddate-' + hmi;
                                }

                            }

                            buildDateForms += '<input type="hidden" value="' + howManyInstallments + '" name="totalinstallments" id="totalinstallments">';
                            buildDateForms += '<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){ $("';
                            buildDateForms += addingIdNames;
                            buildDateForms += '").datepicker({});});<\/script>';
                            if (howManyInstallments != 0) {
                                $('.showinstallmentdates').html(buildDateForms);
                            } else {
                                $('.showinstallmentdates').html('');
                            }

                        });
                    });
                });
$("#btn-add-form").on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Applications/Controllers/Quotes/ajax-add-sin.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#addform').serialize(),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (sinData) {
            $('body').html(sinData);
        }
    });
});
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="section-9">

            <form id="addform" method="post">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-12">

                        <div class="table-responsive" id="addsection">

                            <table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped">

                                <thead>
                                <th>Number</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Installments</th>
                                <th>Contact Name</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input name="addnumber" type="text" class="form-control" id="addnumber" value="" placeholder="Enter CPO Number"></td>
                                        <td><input name="addprice" type="text" class="form-control" id="addprice" value="" placeholder="Enter CPO Number"></td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger addi">Installments</a></td>
                                        <td><input name="addcontactname" type="text" class="form-control" id="addcontactname" value="" placeholder="Enter Contact Name"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>

                            </table>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-12" id="addformajax"></div>

                    <div class="col-sm-12 margin-top-15">

                        <p><button id="btn-add-form" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="button">SUBMIT</button></p>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sends an empty form, which means the form still is not sent, thanks for the help though :)

Comment: 1. set name attribute to all input fields.  2. In ajax change  "data: new FormData(this)" to "data: $('#addform').serialize()".  I have updated the code above "complete code"

Comment: Hi @Rajesh Karunakaran still returns an empty form, its like the form never exists... I have even tried removing the display:none in the css and that did nothing

Comment: The form elements are there because if I do a check using jquery var test = $('addnumber').val(); it brings the correct values in, its just like the form just does not submit what so ever